# Looking for old (maybe 60's) b&w movie with colliding planets and dinosaurs!

Tags: story-identification, movie, planets, dinosaurs

I'm looking for an old SciFi movie I'd seen as a child (a long time ago). I just remember, the earth is colliding with another planet (and it's not "When Worlds collide") and the atmospheres of the 2 planets merge or exchange. Somehow men get to the primordial planet or dinosaurs walk earth, I don't remember which was the case. Maybe men flew by plane... Anybody know the movie and the name or can give me a hint, where to look for. Oh, and by the way, I'm in Germany, just in case you like to show me the way to an allknowing wise man somewhere far beyond ;-)

Comment: To reduce the range of guessing can you be a little more forthcoming about when you were a child? Also, was the movie you saw in German and/or was it translated?

Comment: Can you eliminate any of the options here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_dinosaurs

Comment: I was born 1965 and I think the movie was from sometimes in the 60's. I'd seen it in german TV and so it was translated in german, I don't know the original language. And yes, I can eliminate all options from the wikipedia list.

Comment: Can it be that the men flew away in a balloon? (there have been a few films where a comet hit/scrapped earth and got a few of the inhabitants onto its own surface)

Comment: This is similar on a few points to King Dinosaur by Bert I Gordon. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Dinosaur

Comment: @Thomas: It is possible they flew in an ballon, what films do refer to?

Comment: @Detective Chimp: Thanks, yes that could be the movie. I check if it's been translated.

Comment: @the1andonlydrno not sure i only remember watching about 3 or 4 with these theme and then the guys heading homewards via baloon when the meteor came near to earth again. Was when I was a kid and never memorized the name :/

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question? I am sure that I know the movie and have been looking for the name for quite some time with no luck. When the other planet collided with earth, a large chunk (fur lack of a better description) of earth was transferred to the other planet. A man also transferred and the movie was in part, his struggle to interact with the other people on that planet. If you ever did find the name, I'd sure love to know it.

Answer (score 6):

The person who asked this question isn't onsite any more, but for the record this is probably *Valley of the Dragons* (1961) a b&w version of a Jules Verne story. A comet comes close to the earth, sweeping up two men about to fight a duel. Once aboard the comet the two discover warring primitives and stock footage from 1940's *One Million Years B.C*.